# Handle Textbox and radiobutton event same time in jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox, radio-button

I have bit tricky question, i have a text box on my web page, when i enter something in it and come out of it i have applied the blur event which gets executed. And it sends the value of Textbox using Ajax and then the content get refreshed.

following is the code.

```
 $("input[type=text]").blur(function (e) {

            var valList = [];

            if ($(this).val() != oldVal) {
                var path = $(this).attr("data-path");
                $(".loading").show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("LoadSubControls", "Home")",
                    data: { Name: path, Products: valList },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#divEnquiry").empty().html(response);
                        $(".loading").hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Now my problem is that, i have another control radio button immediately after the Textbox, so when i enter something in Textbox and click on radio button directly only blur event works of textbox, i want to fire the blur and radio button event as well on the same time.

And following is the radio button code.

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function (e) {
            var path = $(this).attr("data-path");
            $(".loading").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("LoadSubControls", "Home")",
                data: { Name: path, Products: valList },
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#divEnquiry").empty().html(response);
                    $(".loading").hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `blur` method just force the click on the `radio` like:

```
$("input[type=radio]").trigger('click');
```

You're considering the user clicks in the radio and not anywhere, but to prevent the later you should check if `radio` is `checked` before triggering it's click event.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as you wanted it to. The only reason I can think of why it is not working would be if your radio button is prechecked and therefore the change event is never fired.

Minimal example :

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<input type="radio" id="radio">

$('#text').on('blur', function(){
  console.log('blur');
});

$('#radio').on('change', function(){
  console.log('change');
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19fhe3tw/1/)